# Topic/Keyword Extraction from a Web Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, keyword

I'm looking for a system to extract topics or simply keywords from a web page, only from the page indicated, without follow the links contained.

The pages to be analyzed belong to different sites, particularly I'd like analyze the links that a person share on Facebook and extract the topics or simply keywords from these pages.

I'd like use Python, but any advice is welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you expect to get keyword data from linked-to pages without sending a request to these pages?

Answer (score 3):

[LXML](http://lxml.de/)

> The lxml XML toolkit is a Pythonic binding for the C libraries libxml2
>   and libxslt. It is unique in that it combines the speed and XML
>   feature completeness of these libraries with the simplicity of a
>   native Python API, mostly compatible but superior to the well-known
>   ElementTree API.

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for parsing HTML documents
>   (including having malformed markup, i.e. non-closed tags, so named
>   after Tag soup). It creates a parse tree for parsed pages that can be
>   used to extract data from HTML, so this library is useful for web
>   scraping — extracting data from websites.

[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

> Scrapy is a fast high-level screen scraping and web crawling
>   framework, used to crawl websites and extract structured data from
>   their pages. It can be used for a wide range of purposes, from data
>   mining to monitoring and automated testing.

[HTQL](http://htql.net/)

> Hyper-Text Query Language (HTQL) is a language for the querying and
>   transformation of HTML, XML and plain text documents. HTQL is
>   developed in C++ with fast and efficient data extraction algorithms.
>   HTQL provides COM and Python interfaces for use in JavaScript, Visual
>   Basic, .NET, ASP, and Python applications.

[mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

> Stateful programmatic web browsing in Python.